# Java: create nonexisting directory on ftp using just URL and URLConnection possible?

Tags: java, url, ftp, java-7

Is it possible to create a nonexisting directory in Java using just the URL class or URLConnection class?

Normally I use something like

`new URL("ftp://"+usr+":"+pass+"@"+srvr+""+existing_dir+""+file).openConnection()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used now the Commons Net Library and their FTP solution.

So now I just need to run
`client.makeDirectory("directory");`